Recursive CTE with window functions
We're on Sql Server 2019, and I'm trying to do some log analysis and I'm trying to get a breakdown by the various levels of a domain name...  i.e. for a domain name with 4 codons (a.b.c.com for example), I want to be able to roll them up by .com, c.com, b.c.com and a.b.c.com.
I've been tinkering with string_split and a recursive cte for a while but the thing that appears to be tripping me up is the recursive portion and how the window functions work (or don't) in that part.
;WITH parts as ( -- break up the domain name and put a number on each piece for windowing functions
   select top 100000 value as dom, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order BY (SELECT NULL)) id
   from string_split('www.google.com', '.')
),
agg as (
        -- try to put the pieces back together
    SELECT cast(dom as varchar(max)) thisLevel,
      cast(LEAD(dom) OVER (order by id desc) as varchar(max)) nextLevel,
      cast(LEAD(dom) OVER (order by id desc) + '.' + dom as varchar(max)) toplevel,
      id,
      MAX(ID) OVER ( order by id desc) maxID
    FROM parts 
    where id > 0
    UNION ALL
        -- The OVER ORDER BY seems to be ignored on the recursion
    SELECT thisLevel, 
      nextLevel,
      cast(nextLevel + '.' + LEAD(topLevel)OVER(ORDER BY Id desc) as varchar(max)) as topLevel,
      id, maxid
    from agg 
    where nextLevel is not null and toplevel is not null
)
    select * from agg

From the anchor pass, I'm getting
com, google, google.com, 3, 3
google, www, www.google, 2, 3
www, NULL, NULL, 1, 3

as I would expect, but the LEAD() OVER (order by id desc) looks like it is ignored, and the recursion starts feeding the anchor batch in reverse order, which is puzzling me.
In the second pass it gets
google, www, null, 2, 3
com, google, null, 3, 3

when order by id desc seems like it should be going {3,2} instead of {2,3}
Am I missing something here?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Analytic and aggregate functions in the recursive part of the CTE are applied to the set for the current recursion level and not to the set for the CTE. Functions like ROW_NUMBER operate only on the subset of data passed to them by the current recursion level and not the entire set of data passed to the recursive part of the CTE

You should probably just provide example data and desired results for the whole thing as I'm not clear what you are attempting here and certainly ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order BY (SELECT NULL)) is not the right approach even before we get to the recursion

On a side note: if you are on SQL2022 or Azure you can use an extra parameter for STRING_SPLIT to get the ordinal number of the split value

When I did this sort of thing for a registrar a decade or two back we found it helpful to add a second column with the original domain's segments in reverse order so that you could index it and use the indexes in tailed like matches, e.g. www.google.com would be stored in the second column as com.google.www and could be matched efficiently with LIKE 'com.google.%'

Thank you all for the responses.  I edited the text to include the Sql Server version I'm on (2019), which was the only bit missing from Yitzhak's suggestions.  The 2019 is the reason why I'm using the ROW_NUMBER() OVER clause to generate the id column, as that 3rd parameter to STRING_SPLIT is not available

Thank you for the link to the documentation, Martin, but I'm still puzzled there.  Yes, I'm expecting the recursion clause window function to operate on the data passed to them by the level of recursion.  What's puzzling me is that the LEAD() OVER (ORDER BY id desc) doesn't appear to be operating properly.  In other words, the ORDER BY id desc clause does not appear to be getting enforced.  The results of the anchor clause are being fed into the recursion in inverse order and the ORDER BY doesn't seem to happen

Always, I was hoping to use the ultimate results in a GROUP BY to get totals rolled up by domain level.  My first pass on this was to just use REVERSE on the host name and use LIKE as you did but found that approach lacking because a bunch of weird domains in Asia have some variation on "www" in like the 4-6 levels of their domain names.  Reordering the codons (STRING_SPLIT and reassemble the pieces in reverse order) would probably help with that.

Thanks for the doc link, Martin, but I'm still puzzled.  Yes, I'm expecting the recursion clause window function to operate on the data passed to them by the previous level of recursion.  What's puzzling me is that the LEAD() OVER (ORDER BY id desc) doesn't appear to be operating properly.  In other words, the ORDER BY id desc clause does not appear to be getting enforced.  The results of the anchor clause are being fed into the recursion in inverse order and the ORDER BY doesn't seem to happen.  The clause doesn't throw an error (like a GROUP or ORDER by below); it just doesn't do it.

5 minute timer on comment edits ran out, which is why there's a dupe
